# Finding Collisions In The Hash

Tags: c#, .net, hash

So for a certain task I was asked to find collisions for the first n-bits (n will be 4, 8 ...) of a `SHA256` digest between 2 random 64 byte sequence, which I do viz.

```
SHA256Managed hashstring = new SHA256Managed();
byte[] hash_1 = hashstring.ComputeHash(a);
...
```

I compute the string value for the hashes viz.

```
string hashString = string.Empty;
foreach (byte x in hash)
{
    hashString += String.Format("{0:x2}", x);
}
return hashString;
```

And I use the string matching function to first extract, say the first 8 bits:

```
string first8Char_hash1 = new string(hashDisplay(hash_1).Take(8).ToArray());
```

check if the first say, 8 bits match or not, viz.

```
if (first8Char_hash1.Equals(first8Char_hash2))
{
    //Do something
}
```

Now, if I do, say the first 4 bits, I find a collision within say an average 12,000 iterations, however, for the first 8 bits, well I am unable to find a collision even after 1,00,00 tries.

What's the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: You are comparing bytes by converting them to an iterable, then that to an array, then that to a string; can you think of a better way to compare bytes for equality?

Comment: "Until the program crashes" with what error? `OutOfMemoryException`? Also, I wouldn't use LINQ and call `Take(8)` and later a `string.Equals()` on it, but just use a standard `for` loop and break out as soon as one bit doesn't match.

Comment: You have confused bits with bytes. Bytes are eight bits.

Comment: As for your actual question: do some math. How many hashes do you *expect* to need to make in order to find a collision on 64 bits = 8 bytes?

Comment: Why the -ve vote? I was confused and hashing is new to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you print a number as hex, each 4 bits become *one* hex character. If you would like to find collisions among the first 4 bits, you compare one character, not four. Four characters correspond to 16-bit collisions.

For eight bits, compare the first two characters of the hex string.

Comment: That is certainly a problem but there is a bigger problem here; a collision within the first four bits should be detected in about 10 tries, not 12000.  I think the OP is confused about the difference between bits and bytes.

Comment: The right to binary conversion code would be `Convert.ToString(x, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');` instead of that `{0:x2}` format specifier you have